# order ggplot by a separate column

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to order this ggplot on the base of a different column which is not plot. Is that possible?

This is my subset of data

```
test<- structure(list(
  Mutations = c(
    "P9L",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "P9L",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "P9Q",
    "P9S",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "P9Q",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "P9Q",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "P9S",
    "P9L",
    "S12P",
    "S12P",
    "S12P",
    "S12P",
    "S12P",
    "S12P",
    "S12P",
    "C15S",
    "C15S",
    "C15F",
    "C15F",
    "C15F",
    "C15F",
    "C15F",
    "C15S",
    "C15F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F",
    "L18F"
  ),
  x = c(
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    9L,
    12L,
    12L,
    12L,
    12L,
    12L,
    12L,
    12L,
    15L,
    15L,
    15L,
    15L,
    15L,
    15L,
    15L,
    15L,
    15L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L,
    18L
  ),
  epi_week = c(
    51L,
    53L,
    53L,
    54L,
    55L,
    55L,
    55L,
    56L,
    57L,
    57L,
    58L,
    58L,
    59L,
    59L,
    59L,
    60L,
    60L,
    60L,
    61L,
    61L,
    62L,
    62L,
    53L,
    55L,
    56L,
    57L,
    58L,
    60L,
    61L,
    52L,
    54L,
    56L,
    57L,
    58L,
    59L,
    60L,
    61L,
    62L,
    49L,
    50L,
    51L,
    52L,
    53L,
    54L,
    55L,
    56L,
    57L,
    58L,
    59L,
    60L
  ),
  n = c(
    0.018412815,
    0.015021782,
    0.015021782,
    0.010515247,
    0.024205261,
    0.032273681,
    0.00806842,
    0.023421032,
    0.080858175,
    0.048514905,
    0.036714089,
    0.073428178,
    0.045506257,
    0.053090633,
    0.007584376,
    0.040013338,
    0.026675559,
    0.00666889,
    0.134355489,
    0.023709792,
    0.037509377,
    0.012503126,
    0.015021782,
    0.01613684,
    0.015614021,
    0.016171635,
    0.009178522,
    0.013337779,
    0.031613056,
    0.027144408,
    0.010515247,
    0.007807011,
    0.016171635,
    0.018357045,
    0.037921881,
    0.013337779,
    0.007903264,
    0.012503126,
    0.16722408,
    0.353495679,
    0.699686982,
    1.221498371,
    1.727504882,
    3.238696109,
    4.260125867,
    3.70833008,
    3.913535658,
    2.065167508,
    2.935153584,
    2.734244748
  ),
  mab = c(
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L
  ),
  support = c(
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L,
    1L
  )
),
row.names = c(NA,
              50L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code for the plot

```
p1 <- ggplot(test, aes(x = epi_week, y = Mutations, fill = n))+  
  geom_tile() + coord_equal() +  scale_fill_gradient(trans = "log",low="white", high="darkgreen", guide_legend(title = "Percentage (%)", title.position = "top"), labels = function(x) sprintf("%.2f", x)) + theme(
    # Hide panel borders and remove grid lines
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    # Remove panel background
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    # Change axis line
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1, size=5,color="black")
    )

p1

p1 + geom_tile(data=test, aes(colour=factor(support, c(1,2,3)),  size=factor(support,c(1,2,3))), alpha=0) + 
  scale_colour_manual("Confidence", values=c("white", "c(1,2,3)),  size=factor(support,c(1,2,3))), alpha=0) + 
  scale_colour_manual("Confidence", values=c("white", "blue4","red")) + 
  scale_size_manual("Confidence", values=c(0,0.2,0.2))
```

Mutations are names with a letter follow by a number and then another letter (e.g. R377L).

in my data I have a column x that have all the numbers.
How can I order my y axis in the ggplot (which is Mutations) by descending x values ?

I am also wondering if it is possible to have some column annotations aside the plot with data from the mab column?

THanks

Comment: it's tough to help without a sample of your data (using `dput`). however, check out the `reorder` function

Comment: Sure, sorry I have just added a subset of the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reorder(Mutations,-epi_week)` to reorder Mutations based on the corresponding mean values of epi_week within each Mutation, see [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reorder.factor.html) too:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = epi_week, y = reorder(Mutations,-epi_week), fill = n))+  
geom_tile() + coord_equal() +  
scale_fill_gradient(trans = "log",low="white", high="darkgreen", 
guide_legend(title = "Percentage (%)", title.position = "top"), labels = function(x) sprintf("%.2f", x)) + theme(
    # Hide panel borders and remove grid lines
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    # Remove panel background
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    # Change axis line
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1, size=5,color="black")
    )
```

[image]

If you want to reorder by its numerical value after stripping it of strings, it will be:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = epi_week, 
y = reorder(Mutations,-as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]*","",Mutations))), 
fill = n))+  
geom_tile() + coord_equal() + ylab("Mutation")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.but I think there was a misunderstanding. x in my plot is epi_week. but it is not what I am looking for. I want the mutations in order by the number that defines the mutations (that number is listed in the column "x" of my dataset test, which is not "epi_week"

Comment: what numbers? can you be a bit more clear. i am not the only one misunderstanding your question

Comment: Yes. sorry my fault. Examples of Mutations are C15F, P9Q, S12P etc  I want them in the y axis ordered as P9Q, S12P, C15F, etc. (following the number in the name, 9,12,15 etc)

Comment: But thanks a lot I managed to fix following your suggestion ```p1 <- ggplot(test, aes(x = epi_week, y = reorder(Mutations,x), fill = n))+  
  geom_tile() ```

Comment: Do you know how to add an additional colour bar (on the right side of the plot) for a further column of my dataset (mab)?